# Show every subgroup of order $5^3$ of $S_{15} \cong \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Show that every subgroup of order $5^3$ of the Symmetric Group $S_{15}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

I thought about the p-Sylow laws first, but didn't find any relation. Might it be true that all members of that subgroups are of order 5? 
Can you please help me to find an approach?

Comment: Well, $S_{15}$ has no element of order $25$ or $125$, so any ABELIAN subgroup of $S_{15}$ must be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$. However, I don't have a good justification why any subgroup of order $125$ must be abelian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $H \leq S_{15}$ such that $|H| = 125$.  For any non-identity $a \in H$, we know that $|a| = 5, 25 \text{ or } 125$ by Lagrange's theorem.

Recall that, for any $\pi \in S_n$, we know $|\pi|$ will be the least common multiple of the cycle lengths when $\pi$ has been decomposed into a composition of disjoint cycles.  Applying this, can you see why $|a| \neq 25 \text{ and } 125$?  So it is indeed true that every non-identity element of $H$ has order $5$.

Now, I claim that $H = \langle a, b, c \rangle$ where $a, b, c \in H$ are disjoint $5$-cycles (which commute with each other).  Suppose for contradiction this were not true.  Then we could find two $5$-cycles $x, y \in H$ that are not disjoint and also do not generate the same subgroup.

We can then consider the element $xy$.  Once you've shown that $xy$ cannot be written either as a single $5$-cycle or a composition of disjoint $5$-cycles, then notice that $|xy| \neq 5$.  This is a contradiction!

Therefore, $H$ is generated by $3$ disjoint $5$ cycles that commute with each other, so $H$ is abelian.  You can now use the structure theorem to finish up.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: I thought about your proof over and over again, and still don't quite understand the part why a,b and c generate $H$ and why your argument suffices for the contradiction. If you say *three disjoint 5-cycles generate H*, wouldn't the contradiction look like "three disjoint 5-cycles don't generate H*, why do you use two (instead of three) **not** disjoint (instead of disjoint) cycles?

Comment: For contradiction, I am indeed assuming that "three disjoint 5-cycles do not generate H".  I am then saying that this would imply that we are guaranteed to find two elements of H, call them $x$ and $y$, such that $x$ and $y$ are not disjoint, and at the same time, do not generate the same subgroups.  I.e. $\langle x \rangle \neq \langle y \rangle$.  From here, I am then turning my focus to the element $xy$ and showing that its order cannot possibly be $5$, as we would expect.

Comment: For example, $x$ might be $(12345)$ whereas $y$ might be $(56789)$.  $x$ and $y$ both move $5$ around.  However, the subgroup $x$ generates and the subgroup $y$ generates are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment, the only elements of order a power of $\;5\;$ in $\;S_3\;$ are those of order $\;5\;$ , and from here that if we take three **disjoint** $\;5$-cycles here we get an abelian group of order $\;125\;$ as disjoint cycles commute.